# AdBlock subscription link is not executing JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, adblock

I'm working right now with some strange problem. I have created a link which is adding into AdBlock or ABP plugin filter list some exceptions such as:

**AdBlock filter file (adblock_dictionary.txt)**

```
[Adblock Plus 2.0]
! Homepage: http://www.domain.com
@@||domain.com/$document
```

**Specific link**

```
 <a href="abp:subscribe?location=path/to/adblock/adblock_dictionary.txt&amp;title=Sometitle" class="button">Turn off AdBlock</a>
```

If someone wondering what is that, link can be created [here](https://adblockplus.org/abp_linkfactory).

And it working fine, pop up shows up, and filters are added. The problem is, when I want to execute some simple JavaScript function (f.ex. to send data to Google Analytics, or even just `alert('something')`) it not executing a script. Already tried in many ways to run it, with simulating a click, triggering, jQuery, `onclick` ( even with `javascript:function()`) and nothing seems to work, it is just not executing JavaScript while I use this specific link.

**This is not working**

```
<a href="abp:subscribe?location=path/to/adblock/adblock_dictionary.txt&amp;title=Sometitle" class="button" onclick="function()">Turn off AdBlock</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function() {
    alert('Something'); // or other stuff
}
</script>
```

Maybe someone got same problem and solved it? I would be grateful for any concept how to solve it.

**Update**

Still there's no soultion for that. Looking for someone with some idea :)

Answer (score 0):

Because on anchor tag the function where are called should return true to get executed correctly it's not a good way to do it as you do.

You can do though something like that:

```
<a href="javascript:myFunction();">Link</a>
```

And in your js file:

```
function myFunction() {
    var url = 'abp:subscribe?location=path/to/adblock/adblock_dictionary.txt&amp;title=Sometitle'
    var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
    win.focus();
}
```

Of course you can do whatever you want in the function.

Comment: This is not working, while those 3 lines are in function it says: `VM11561:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined(…)`, when I comment it and write some `console.log` it works. Strange, isn't it? Anyway with this link is something strange at all... try to run it via browser adress input, it will google it, not execute. But while it is in `a href` it works.

Comment: That's strange it's a simple function. Did you tried instead not to use an `anchor`? Like `<div onClick="myFunction();">Link</div>`

Comment: Well I didn't see that there is `:` instead of `=`. Anyway right now it goes to `about:blank`, not to this link, and `console.log` logs. Tried already `<div onclick="javascript:myFunction();">Turn off AdBlock</div>` but still same behaviour.

Comment: Yes the `:` was an miss-type but I updated. I'm guessing then that this `abp` is not recognised by the browser. Please inform if you find a better solution or if this worked for you later on. Cheers

Comment: Well browser when `a` is clicked is going to plugin and adds a filter, but maybe there is something up with this `abp:` what aborts JavaScript. Thanks anyway :)